# Symfony - The file exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 0 KiB)

Tags: symfony

I have a problem on Symfony 2.6 trying to upload a PDF File.

When I run the function move on an new UploadedFile I get this error :

The file "exemple_pdf_modifiable.pdf" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 0 KiB).

[image: 1]

When i check phpinfo(), I have these infos :

post_max_size   50M ; upload_max_filesize   50M

[image: 2]

Has anyone ever encountered this issue ? I didnt find any answer to my problem on the web; Thank you !

Comment: Does your project have a `.htaccess` file? Then perhaps setting it there will help. 

`php_value upload_max_filesize 64M`

Comment: I have edited my .htaccess file with these values but it changed nothing. :/